# How to copy a file from azure blob to on-premises file system using azure blob trigger using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, filesystems, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I am trying to create an azure blob trigger to copy the file uploaded to the azure blob to the on-premises file system. Can anyone please provide the steps for the same?

***What I have tried:***
I created a blob trigger and bound its output parameter to external file(preview) and selected the File System API. It asks for Display name, root folder, username and password. What goes here and how to connect azure to my machine's file system?

This is my **function.json** file.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "input/{name}",
      "connection": "connection_Name"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "outputFile",
      "path": "outout/{name}",
      "connection": "file_system_connection_name",
      "direction": "out",
      "typeProperties": {
        "host": "HostName",
        "userid": "userid",
        "password": "userpassword",
        "gatewayName": "gatewayName"
      }
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

This is my  run.csx  file.

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log,Stream outputFile)
{
        myBlob.CopyTo(outputFile);
}
```

Comment: So when a file is added to the blob, the trigger is called. In there, download the blob. You can find how to download the blob on the MS help page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs. Of course, this would download to the machine wherever the code is running. Perhaps it would be better to maintain a DB, indicating when a blob has been added. Have a program on your local machine monitor the db and download new blobs. Then delete the record from the DB or mark it as "complete".

Comment: What do you mean by *on-premises* file system? Are you referring to your own machine (something in your local data center / office / home)? If that's the case: you'd need to have access to an on-premises file system over the Internet, or have some type of service that listens for files (or links to files), running on-prem. And how you do this is really up to you: a 
 fairly broad topic.